# Cannot set the [Key] property of the model when saving new records

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, sql-server-express

So, I've moved to MVC3 and on the whole I think this great; I really like the codefirst approach too.

I have run into a bit of bother today with this and while under MVC2 I was able to add records and edit them I am now unable to do so.

I know that is a vague start so allow me to eloborate.

Here is an example of one of my models

```
namespace ESF_ResourceManager.Models
{
    public class FileList
    {
        [Key]
        public int FileListID { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("File title: ")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please set a unique title for the file")]
        // TODO: Need to add remote validation - must be unique
        public string FileTitle { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Choose a File")]
        [FileExtensions(Extensions = "txt, zip, pdf, ppt, xls, doc, docx, xlsx, pptx", ErrorMessage = "Please choose a valid file of type txt, zip, pdf, ppt, xls, doc, docx, xlsx or pptx")]
        public HttpPostedFileBase FileUrl { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Then the corresponding controller:

```
namespace ESF_ResourceManager.Controllers
{
    public class FileListController : ResourceManagerController
    {
        //
        // GET: /FileList/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var fileList = from fl in DBContext.FileLists
                           where fl.FileListID > 0
                           select fl;

            return View(fileList.ToList());
        }


        //
        // GET: /FileList/Create
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /FileList/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FileList fileDetail)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // test the file - size only - the file type should have been checked via Extensions as par tof the model definition
                if (fileDetail.FileUrl.ContentLength > 0 && fileDetail.FileUrl.ContentLength < 1048576)
                {
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileDetail.FileUrl.FileName);
                    string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads/documents"), fileName);
                    fileDetail.FileUrl.SaveAs(path);

                    DBContext.FileLists.Add(fileDetail);
                    DBContext.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");

                }
            }

            return View(fileDetail);
        }

        //
        // GET: /FileList/Edit/5
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            var fileDetail = from fl in DBContext.FileLists
                             where fl.FileListID == id
                             select fl;
            return View(fileDetail.Single());
        }

        //
        // POST: /FileList/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, FileList fileDetail)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var fileEdited = DBContext.FileLists.Find(id);
                UpdateModel(fileEdited);
                DBContext.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View();

        }

        //
        // GET: /FileList/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            var fileDetail = from fl in DBContext.FileLists
                             where fl.FileListID == id
                             select fl;
            return View(fileDetail.Single());
        }

        //
        // POST: /FileList/Delete/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, FileList fileDetail)
        {
            try
            {
                DBContext.FileLists.Remove(DBContext.FileLists.Find(id));
                DBContext.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The view which is Razor is (for create):

```
@model ESF_ResourceManager.Models.FileList

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "File List";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "FileList", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset>
            <legend>File List</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FileTitle)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FileTitle)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FileTitle)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FileUrl) 
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FileUrl, new { type = "file" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FileUrl) 
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
```

So, I can load the view and see the form to enter the data but when I click the Create button I get the following message:

> **Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key**

I have looked at the object in the debugger and nothing on the object coming into the create post function is null. the key is 0 and I would have expected (possibly wrongly) for this to be 1.

So my first question is what have I missed here? What do I need to do to get this to work properly for me?

The second question is more general - where is my data? The tutorials I have read on this suggest that ther eis either a SQLExpress database created some place or a SqlCE in the App_Data. Neither of which I can find so I'm confused as to where this is.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks
nathj07

**EDIT**

Thanks for stopping by, I'm still learning what would be helpful to include when asking questions. So, here are the requested items:

**Data Context**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace ESF_ResourceManager.Models
{
    public class ResourceManagerContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Resource> Resources { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ResourceType> ResourceTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<FileList> FileLists { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Web.Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->

<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

And finally -

**Views/Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>

    <!--
        Enabling request validation in view pages would cause validation to occur
        after the input has already been processed by the controller. By default
        MVC performs request validation before a controller processes the input.
        To change this behavior apply the ValidateInputAttribute to a
        controller or action.
    -->
    <pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If there is anything else you need to see then I'll happily post it up.

Thanks
nathj07

**Edit 2**
I have now tried adding a SQLExpress database manually and updating the connection string in the web.config file.

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=True;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|DB_ESF_ResourceManager.mdf;User Instance=true" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

This leaves me with the same error - no difference at all. I'm at a complete loss with this and have no idea where to go next with it. Are there any more suggestions on this?

Thanks
nathj07

Comment: two more things we might need 1) your databasecontext class and your web.config if you have explicitly specified a connection string

Comment: What is excatly the problem now? The exception you mentioned above (I've just highlighted the message)? Or don't you find or can't create the database?

Comment: Ok, the problem is no a little different. Basically I tried recreating this work. The project had 4 models - resource types, resource, users and file list. Having recreated all bar the file list one I noticed that everything is working just fine. I add the filelist model as shown and I get the error. This time I have no connection strings and I assume (bad I know) this has created a DB some place in either SQLServerExpress or CE. I am now left with a couple of other questions but I will post those in new threads. Thanks for all the help. I will upvote accordingly

nathj07

Comment: How can you "assume" that a database has been created? Can't you simply check if the DB is there or not? And if you don't specify any connection string at all it will be a SQL Server Express DB (see my answer below). The database is really the first thing you must find to identify the reason for your exception.

Comment: Hi Slauma, I agree completely. The thing us I don't know how to find the db. Sql management express is not finding anything to connect to. Any ideas on how I can find this?

Comment: Hi, I've got it sorted. It turns out I was missing something in my understanding regarding how to connect to the SQLServer express database. Anyway, now I have that I can find the DB and see what is going on in there.
Thanks to everyone for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that EF doesn't mark your key as an identity column. Entity Framework marks a property as a primary key if the type is `int`, `short` or `long`, and the name is `<classname>Id`. On your model, the 'ID' part is in upper case. You have two possible solutions:

- Placing the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` above your property, to indicate that it is in fact an identity column
- Renaming your property from `FileListID` to `FileListId`. You'll probably won't need the `[Key]` attribute anymore either if you go for this solution.

If you go for the first solution, your property will look like this:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int FileListID { get; set; }
```

Comment: Primary or Foreign detection is not case sensitive, so both `ID` and `Id` is fine.

Comment: Slauma, thanks for clarifying that. I thought it was case insensitive as I have a demo solution working with upper case ID.

Comment: Jesse, thanks for the tip on setting the [DatabaseGenerated] annotation,that has taught me something new which is great.

Answer (score 0):

you need too add FileListID for the mvc make bind

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FileListID)
```

Comment: Hi Fernando, I tried adding a visible field previously and that made no difference. I'll try a hidden field when I'm back at work. Thanks nathj07

Comment: Hi again Fernando - -the code was in dropbox so I tried it from home and that hasn't worked. Do you have any more answers? I did add some more code to the original question. Thanks again for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

Your second question:

Because you don't have any connection string in your web.config file Entity Framework 4.1 will try to create a new database in your SQL Server Express instance if the database doesn't exist. The name of this database is **Namespace.DerivedContextName**, so in your case it should be: **ESF_ResourceManager.Models.ResourceManagerContext**.

You can take a look at the database with SQL Server Management Studio or in Visual Studio via the Server Explorer.

Your first question:

A possible reason why you get your error is that the key column in the database corresponding to the key property `FileListID` in your model is not marked as an identity column, i.e. as a column which automatically generates its own value when you insert a new row. Your model configuration assumes that the column is an identity (by default, you didn't switch that off). As a consequence EF won't send a value for `FileListID` to the database when you insert a new object because it assumes that the database will create a value. If the column in the database isn't an identity it doesn't create a value and you get your exception.

So, you should check in the DB if `FileListID` is an identity column and if not, turn that on.